# Ionic 3 image upload form using REST API

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I am trying to upload a form containing an image to a server. All form data is uploaded properly but the image is not uploaded in the correct format to the MySQL DB, so a blank image is displayed. Any help is appreciated. I am really stuck here.

Below is my .html file:

```
<ion-content padding class="my-page">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>Enter Title </ion-label>
        <ion-input [(ngModel)]="regData.title" name="title" type="text"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <button ion-button color="secondary" (click)="getImage()">Select Image</button>

    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="regData.img" name="img" type="text" [readonly]="true" value="{{imgurl}}"></ion-input>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>Enter Description</ion-label>
        <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="regData.description" name="description" type="text" rows="3"></ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>

    <button ion-button block (click)="addPost()">  Add Data </button>
</ion-content>
```

Below is my .ts file:

```
import {
    Camera,
    CameraOptions
} from "@ionic-native/camera";

import {
    FileTransfer,
    FileUploadOptions,
    FileTransferObject
} from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';


export class Addnews {


    imgurl: any;

    regData = {
        title: '',
        img: '',
        description: ''
    };

    constructor(private transfer: FileTransfer, private camera: Camera) {}

    getImage() {
        const options: CameraOptions = {
            quality: 100,
            sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
            destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
        }
        this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
            this.imgurl = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
        }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
            this.presentToastImg(err);
        });
    }

    addPost() {
        this.showLoader();
        this.adddataApiProvider.adddata(this.regData).then((result) => {
            this.loading.dismiss();
            this.successToast();
        }, (err) => {
            this.loading.dismiss();
            this.presentToast(err);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Could you show the image upload `code` also?

Comment: All I have code is given above.. I havn't used the image upload code... all code is given above...thank you..for immediate response,sir..

Comment: Are you saving image as a blob in db? or as a file in server?

Comment: I have stored image in mysql db server as file type. eg. uploads/demoimg.jpg

Comment: if you are using file transfer with file url, dont append this: `this.imgurl =  'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;`

Comment: I tried this one.. But image is not stored in db in respected format.

Comment: Image is stored in mysql db in format => content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A9481  But i want to store it in format as => uploads/demoimg.jpg. How to achieve it..???